# Magic link to how to ask page

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

Apologies if this is a duplicate, couldn't find one to vote on.

Can we have a *how to ask* magic link like `[help]`?

```
[how-to-ask] => http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
```

At the moment I have to keep looking this url up when pointing new users to this page. This would make life much easier.

I actually think there are several of these needed, see [Add a magic link to point to the “minimal working example” help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217103/add-a-magic-link-to-point-to-the-minimal-working-example-help-page) also.

Comment: Additional, it could be useful to add a button on the review pages from the review queue to fast add a **decent massage** pointing out new members to the how-to-ask page.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Quoting from the [comment formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) (linked from the `help` box on comments):

> `[ask]`, `[answer]` – link to the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) or [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) page.

Someone must've nicked a time machine and sneaked that in sometime in the past.

Comment: Damn it! I looked for this but couldn't find anything, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Just a quick knock on the door, is this still working? I tried it on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374733/can-we-add-a-link-to-https-stackoverflow-com-help-how-to-ask-on-https-stacko but it does not seem to render correctly

Comment: @StigPerez: yes, those work just fine, in comments. See: `[ask]` renders as [ask], and `[answer]` renders as [answer].

Comment: Ah...I forgot to encapsulate it with ticks, now it works!