# Can we add a link to how to ask on the tour, optionally with a badge for reading it

Tags: feature-request, help-center, badge-request, tour-page

I just went through a review queue marathon and although the life of a rookie-reviewer is tough (and for good reasons) I very often find myself referring new users to [*how to ask*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I see there is a [badge called "informed"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed) for reading through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) page, but that page does not contain a link to *how to ask*.

With the danger of opening a flood of opinion-based answers my question is if this would be a good idea, or even have a separate badge for reading through the ask page?

Comment: I like the idea for the simple reason that it would have the effect to make it visible whether an asker has read the howto or not.

Comment: New users are already [shown a summary page on how to ask, and have to tick a box on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?) to acknowledge that they have read it. Next, the [asking a question form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) has a *How to Ask* sidebar. Both link to the full page.  A badge is not going to improve their reading skills!

Comment: But badges are fun and I want more badges!